# Help with PDE having variable coefficients

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am currently working on a problem on spheres, in which there is a function Q that is dependent on radius r and time t. I am interested in solving a PDE that gives a picture of evolution of Q over time. I was recommended to use Mathematica since its easier to plot it and so on. The equation is:
[image: PDE Equation]

where k is a proportionality constant, c is a central value of the sphere, G is the gravitational constant and $\alpha$ depends on $\kappa$ and G. I chose to run with:
$\kappa$ = 1; G = $6.67408*10^{-11}$; c = 20; $α = \sqrt{k/(2 \pi G)}$ = 48833.1

My initial code was:

```
pde = D[Q[r, t], {t, 2}] - 
   2*k*c*α*(((Cos[r/α])/(rα)) - ((Sin[
          r/α]/r^2)))*D[Q[r, t], {r, 1}] - 
   2*k*c*α*((Sin[r/α]/r)*D[Q[r, t], {r, 2}]) + (2*k*
      c*α*(((Cos[r/α])/(rα)) - ((Sin[r/α]/
           r^2)))*D[
       Q[r, t], {r, 1}])/((cα*(Sin[r/α]/r)) + 
      Q[r, t]) - 4*π*G*c*α*(Sin[r/α]/r)*Q[r, t] == 0
i1 := Q[0, t] == 2
i2 := Q[r, 0] == 1

sol = NDSolve[{pde, i1, i2}, Q[r, t], {r, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

with "test" initial conditions since it wasn't working. After tackling a horde of errors I couldn't figure out where I was going wrong (I assume the problem is due to a variable coefficient) and so I tried simplifying it using variable separation [Q(r,t) = R(r)T(t)] which split it into two parts, the time component:

```
DSolve[(1/T[t]) D[T[t], {t, 2}] == -L^2, T[t], t]
```

which works, and the spatial component:

```
eqn = -2 k c α ((Cos[r/α]/α r) - (Sin[r/α]/r^2)) (1/R[r]) R'[r] - 
   2 k c α (Sin[r/α]/r) (1/R[r]) R''[r] + 
   2 k ((Cot[r/α]/α) - (1/r)) (1/R[r]) R'[r] - 
   4 π G c α (Sin[r/α]/r) == L^2
i3 = R[3] == 5
i4 = R[2] == 2
sol = NDSolve[{eqn, i3, i4}, R[r], r]
```

which gives an error. The initial conditions here too are guesses.

My questions are, where am I going wrong, and how would I go about plotting Q(r,t)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Constants $k,c,\alpha, G$ are not defined.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I tried running with it numerical values for k,c,α,G, still gives the same error. Perhaps should have included that.

Comment: @Tjis Yes, please, show us numerical values of constants  $k,c,\alpha, G$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have edited it in to the question.

Comment: @Tjis thank you! Why in your first code `i1=2, i2=1`? Do you suppose that `Q[r,t]` not unique   at `r=0,t=0`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Q[r,t] is expected to be unique at r=0,t=0. Its just that when running the code, there was a need for boundary conditions and i1=2, i2=1 is just the latest set of (wrong) test boundary conditions I played around with.

Comment: @Tjis Ok! Let have a look at my answer with `i1=i2=1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve problem with `i1=i2` in the first code, therefore we suppose that solution is unique:

```
k = 1; G = 6.67408*10^{\[Minus]11}; r0 = 
 10^-3; r1 = 5; c = 20; \[Alpha] = k/Sqrt[2 Pi G];
pde = D[Q[r, t], {t, 2}] - 
    2*k*c*\[Alpha]*(((Cos[r/\[Alpha]])/(r \[Alpha])) - ((Sin[
           r/\[Alpha]]/r^2)))*D[Q[r, t], {r, 1}] - 
    2*k*c*\[Alpha]*((Sin[r/\[Alpha]]/r)*D[Q[r, t], {r, 2}]) + (2*k*
       c*\[Alpha]*(((Cos[r/\[Alpha]])/(r \[Alpha])) - ((Sin[
             r/\[Alpha]]/r^2)))*
       D[Q[r, t], {r, 1}])/((c \[Alpha]*(Sin[r/\[Alpha]]/r)) + 
       Q[r, t]) - 4*\[Pi]*G*c*\[Alpha]*(Sin[r/\[Alpha]]/r)*Q[r, t] == 
   0;
bc = Q[r0, t] == 1;
ic = Q[r, 0] == 1; ic1 = Derivative[0, 1][Q][r, 0] == 0;


sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc, ic, ic1}, Q, {r, r0, r1}, {t, 0, 10^3}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 41, "MaxPoints" -> 81, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]

Plot3D[sol[r, t], {r, r0, 5}, {t, 0, 10^3}, Mesh -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. An amateurish question: Is there a possible way to display the functional form as the output?

Comment: @Tjis What kind of functional you supposed to display?

Comment: A function as the output of the PDE instead of the data points for Q[r,t]

Comment: @Tjis Did you pay attention that we use `sol=NDSolveValue[...]`. The output is the numerical solution in a form of interpolation function `sol[r, t]`.